# Data is not saving in mysql db

Tags: php

My code is below, and i am not understanding that what problem is in this code, because my data is not saving in mysql db table. Is anyone tell me that what problem is in my code?
    ===========================================================================================

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('csv_data',$con) or die(mysql_error());

    $data = array();
    if(isset($_FILES['submit'])){
        if($FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0){
            $file = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($file,"r");

        while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 134217728, ',')){
            $query = "INSERT INTO data(url) VALUES ('".$data[0]."')";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "File Uploaded.";

        }
    }
}
?>
<body>
<form name="frm" action="save_csv_in_mysql_table.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="csv_file" value="Upload Csv File"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload CSV File"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Try using error handlers.

Comment: Not `if(isset($_FILES['submit'])){` but `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` for `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload CSV File"/>` or you might have meant to use `if(isset($_FILES['csv_file'])){` to work with `<input type="file" name="csv_file" value="Upload Csv File"/>` - Might be opening up a potential "can of worms", as it were. Try either/or.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because `E_DOEST_WORK` is not a proper PHP error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

PHP:

```
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('csv_data',$con) or die(mysql_error());

    $data = array();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0){
            $file = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($file,"r");

            while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 134217728, ',')){
                $query = "INSERT INTO data(url) VALUES ('".$data[0]."')";
                mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "File Uploaded.";

             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Let's hope this one's not a "can of worms" as it were ;-) Good luck

Comment: Now this error is generating:- Notice: Undefined variable: FILES in D:\xampp\htdocs\Get_Set_CSV\save_csv_in_mysql_table.php on line 29

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"  missing in your form

Comment: I knew it. So many things not going "right" with OP's code, it's not funny.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer was right this one:- if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

Comment: But you did not tell me about it:- <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm" action="save_csv_in_mysql_table.php" method="post" >

Comment: @user2965171 check in my comments, I have mentioned about the enctype

Comment: Yes, user876345 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is $_FILES['submit']? I think, you have not this index.

Try to add in the beginning

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

and than create a normal statement.

For example:

```
if (isset($_FILES['csv_file'])) {do something}
```

At the second: don't use INSERT with mysql_query. Read about PDO, it's safe and comfort. There is a vulnerability in your code (SQL Injection).

Answer (score 0):

You have built your form incorrectly, so NO FILE IS BEING UPLOADED:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm" action="save_csv_in_mysql_table.php" method="post" >
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--missing
```

You then failed to check if an upload was actually successful and simply blundered onwards blindly:

```
if (isset($_FILES['csv_file']['error']) && ($_FILES['csv_file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
   die("Upload failed with error code#: " . $_FILES['csv_file']['error']);
}
```

You then blindly try to slurp data from this file and insert that data directly into your query string, also leaving you wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I knew that question was a "can of worms". So many things not going "right".

Comment: Thanks, Your answer was right this one:- <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm" action="save_csv_in_mysql_table.php" method="post" >